# How to read text file which is similar to json format

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas to manipulate a .txt file but I get this error:

```
 pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 12
```

I have tried to read the pandas docs, but found nothing.

My code like:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    df = pd.read_csv('McKData_2511.txt')
```

My text file look like:

```
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'42023015925','Brand':'Generic Equivalent to Adrenalin®','Manufacturer':'Par Sterile Products LLC','CountryofOrigin':'United States','AlternatePackaging':'CT/25','Application':'Alpha- and Beta-Adrenergic Agonist','ContainerType':'Single Use Vial','DosageForm':'Injection','GenericDrugCode':'26184','GenericDrugName':'Epinephrine','NDCNumber':'42023-0159-25','StorageRequirements':'USP Controlled Room Temperature','Strength':'1 mg / mL (1:1000)','UNSPSCCode':'51391743','Volume':'1 mL'}
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'00573016040','Manufacturer':'Pfizer','CountryofOrigin':'Unknown','ActiveIngredients':'Ibuprofen','Application':'Pain Relief','ContainerType':'Bottle','DosageForm':'Tablet','GenericDrugCode':'35743','NDCNumber':'00573-0160-40','Strength':'200 mg Strength','UNSPSCCode':'51384509','Volume':'100 per Bottle'}
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'33332041910','Brand':'Afluria® Quadrivalent 2019 - 2020','Manufacturer':'Seqirus USA Inc','CountryofOrigin':'Australia','Application':'Flu Vaccine','ContainerType':'Multiple Dose Vial','DosageForm':'Injection','NDCNumber':'33332041910','StorageRequirements':'Requires Refrigeration','Strength':'60 mcg / 0.5 mL','Type':'Intramuscular','UNSPSCCode':'51201608','User':'Indicated For People 6 Months of Age and Above','Volume':'5 mL'}
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'04110081127','Brand':'Afrin® Allergy Sinus','Manufacturer':'Bayer','CountryofOrigin':'Unknown','ActiveIngredients':'Oxymetazoline HCl','Application':'Sinus Relief','ContainerType':'Bottle','DosageForm':'Nasal Spray','Strength':'0.05% Strength','UNSPSCCode':'51162732','Volume':'15 mL'}
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'04110081125','Brand':'Afrin® Original','Manufacturer':'Bayer','CountryofOrigin':'Unknown','ActiveIngredients':'Oxymetazoline HCl','Application':'Sinus Relief','ContainerType':'Bottle','DosageForm':'Nasal Spray','Strength':'0.05% Strength','UNSPSCCode':'51162732','Volume':'30 mL'}
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'17478025310','Brand':'AK-Fluor®','Manufacturer':'Akorn','CountryofOrigin':'United States','Application':'Ophthalmic Disclosing Agent','ContainerType':'Single Dose Vial','DosageForm':'Injection','GenericDrugCode':'27760','GenericDrugName':'Fluorescein Sodium','NDCNumber':'17478025310','Strength':'10%, 500 mg / 5 mL','Type':'Intravenous','UNSPSCCode':'51441603','Volume':'5 mL'}
        Error 487990425
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'00487950103','Manufacturer':'Nephron Pharmaceutical','CountryofOrigin':'Unknown','AlternateManufacturerNumber':'1978717','Application':'Beta-Adrenergic Agonist','ContainerType':'Nebulizer Vial','DosageForm':'Solution','GenericDrugCode':'41681','GenericDrugName':'Albuterol Sulfate, Preservative Free','HCPCS':'J7609','NDCNumber':'00487-9501-03','Strength':'0.083%, 2.5 mg / 3 mL','Type':'Unit Dose, Inhalation','UNSPSCCode':'51391703','Volume':'30 Vials'}
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'00591379760','CountryofOrigin':'Unknown','AlternateManufacturerNumber':'1151067','Application':'Beta-Adrenergic Agonist','ContainerType':'Nebulizer Vial','DosageForm':'Solution','GenericDrugCode':'41681','GenericDrugName':'Albuterol Sulfate, Preservative Free','NDCNumber':'00591-3797-60','Strength':'0.083%, 2.5 mg / 3 mL','Type':'Unit Dose, Inhalation','UNSPSCCode':'51391703','Volume':'60 Vials'}
        Error 4879908743
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'01093974344','Manufacturer':'McKesson Brand','CountryofOrigin':'Unknown','ActiveIngredients':'Ethyl Alcohol','Application':'Antiseptic','ContainerType':'Bottle','DosageForm':'Topical Solution','Strength':'70% Strength','UNSPSCCode':'42295421','Volume':'16 oz.'}
        ,{'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'70677000601','Brand':'sunmark®','Manufacturer':'McKesson Brand','CountryofOrigin':'Unknown','ActiveIngredients':'Cetirizine HCl','Application':'Allergy Relief','ContainerType':'Box','DosageForm':'Tablet','NDCNumber':'70677-0006-01','Strength':'10 mg Strength','UNSPSCCode':'51313101','Volume':'30 per Box'}
```

how can i read this into pandas dataframe with this data only as in some line many values are missing for that line the value should contain null like 
Brand is in first row but not in second row so for second row it should be null

As i want these values only
ManufacturerNo
UNSPSCCode
Brand
Manufacturer
NDC
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Maybe this is because `read_cvs` works with .cvs files?

Comment: If it’s similar to JSON, why not try parsing it as JSON first? It looks valid to me, although there is something weird about those single quotes.

Comment: I tried to read the given sample file as text and then loading each line as JSON data and storing it to a list, gives an error. 

"Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

Comment: Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Read the entire txt file into a string and dump it to a JSON.

Comment: There's no magic solution to this. The simplest option is probably to write some code to transform the input into a valid JSON or CSV file, and import that into panda.

Comment: try to use : `df=pd.read_csv('data',sep='{|}',engine='python',header=None)
df=df[1].str.split(',',expand=True)` then you will receive columns, and than maybe you want to extract values that you looking for

Comment: hey @sygneto thankyou so much for the help but how can i access the data of these only  ManufacturerNo,UNSPSCCode,Brand,Manufacturer,NDC

Comment: You can choose specific column, and use str.extract function

Comment: hey @sygneto somehow i am not able to use str.extract if you can help please help me

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Have you done any research, anything?

Answer (score 0):

this is my raw approach, maybe that would help you
with this code you will receive columns with your data
example for `ManuFACTURERnO` :

```
df=pd.read_csv('data',sep='{|}',engine='python',header=None)
df=df[1].str.split(',',expand=True)

df_all = pd.concat([df[0],df[1],df[2],df[3],df[4],df[5],df[6],df[7],
                    df[8],df[9],df[10],df[11],df[12],df[13],df[14],
                    df[15],df[16],df[17]]) #concat all columns, if number will be different, edit this line
df_all = pd.DataFrame(df_all)
df_all['ManufacturerNo'] = df_all[0].str.extract(r"(ManufacturerNo':'[0-9]{1,30})",expand=True)
df_all['ManufacturerNo'] = df_all['ManufacturerNo'].replace("ManufacturerNo':'","",regex=True)
print(df_all)

                                              0 ManufacturerNo
0    'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'42023015925'    42023015925
1    'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'00573016040'    00573016040
2    'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'33332041910'    33332041910
3    'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'04110081127'    04110081127
4    'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'04110081125'    04110081125
5    'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'17478025310'    17478025310
6                                          None            NaN
7    'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'00487950103'    00487950103
8    'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'00591379760'    00591379760
9                                          None            NaN
10   'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'01093974344'    01093974344
11   'McKesson':''ManufacturerNo':'70677000601'    70677000601
0    'Brand':'Generic Equivalent to Adrenalin®'            NaN
1                       'Manufacturer':'Pfizer'            NaN
2   'Brand':'Afluria® Quadrivalent 2019 - 2020'            NaN
3                'Brand':'Afrin® Allergy Sinus'            NaN
4                     'Brand':'Afrin® Original'            NaN
5                           'Brand':'AK-Fluor®'            NaN
6                                          None            NaN
7       'Manufacturer':'Nephron Pharmaceutical'            NaN

ManufacturerNo=df_all['ManufacturerNo'].dropna().tolist()
print(ManufacturerNo)
['42023015925', '00573016040', '33332041910', '04110081127', '04110081125', '17478025310', '00487950103', '00591379760', '01093974344', '70677000601']
```

If you want to create columns for other values like `UNSPSCCode` , just create new column using same regex or create new one if neccesary, with replacing name inside for example:
`df_all['UNSPSCCode'].replace("UNSPSCCode':'","",regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

The source file is a bit oddly formatted to be a proper Json file as you mention. As it isn't standard you might have to do some string processing to get this to work.

In general my solution converts the text file into a proper Json format and then lets the pd.read_json do the rest of the work.

```
import pandas as pd
lines = []
with open('McKData_2511.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.startswith('Error'):
            lines.append('{'+line[line.find("''")+1::].strip().replace("'",'"'))

data = pd.read_json('['+','.join(lines)+']',dtype=False)

desired_data = data[['ManufacturerNo','NDCNumber']]
```

This goes through the file line by line, checks it it is an Error line or not. If it doesn't it removes the first McKesson part (easiest way i could find doing this) from the line and replaces the single quotes (') with double ("). It then joins everything together and lets pandas read it as a json string. The dtype has to be set to false or the numbers will be converted to ints or floats (which means you lose the leading zeros of the manufacturer numbers).